# What is the Japanese term for the postwar economic miracle?

Tags: word-requests

In France they have "Les Trente Glorieuses" and in Germany the "Wirtschaftswunder". What is the analog in Japanese?

Edit to elaborate: In the case of France there is a very specific term -- "The Glorious Thirty Years", so there is no question of which period in history we are referring to.

What I am looking for is a similarly specific term in Japanese--provided of course that such a specific term exists. Perhaps just like with Germany ("economic miracle") there is no such  specific term.

The current answer given now is 高度経済成長期, which translates roughly to "period of high economic growth". Is there perhaps a more specific term than that?

Edit #2: In the Wikipedia and Kotobank links, there is also some mention of the post WWI boom, the boom through 1944, and the Meiji Restoration. So might there perhaps be some ambiguity as to what 高度経済成長期 refers to? Or is it unambiguous?

In contrast, there is, presumably, no other period of thirty years in French history which is commonly regarded as "glorious", so there is no ambiguity here. We know you're referring to the postwar era when you talk about "Les Trente Glorieuses".

Similarly, even though the term "economic miracle" is not very specific, I believe in Germany when you talk about "Wirtschaftswunder", people generally take it to refer to the postwar period.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "more specific". WWWJDIC, e.g., has 高度経済成長 = "rapid economic growth (esp. that of Japan in the post-WWII period)". The French and German words don't explicitly include "post-war", although are understood to mean "post-WWII rapid economic growth", just like the word 高度経済成長.

Answer (score 5):

I think it's [高度成長](http://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%AB%98%E5%BA%A6%E6%88%90%E9%95%B7) (こうどせいちょう) or more fully [高度経済成長](http://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%AB%98%E5%BA%A6%E7%B5%8C%E6%B8%88%E6%88%90%E9%95%B7) (こうどけいざいせいちょう).

There's also an article for [高度経済成長](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%AB%98%E5%BA%A6%E7%B5%8C%E6%B8%88%E6%88%90%E9%95%B7) on Wikipedia.

Comment: just adding that the period itself would be 高度経済成長*期*